# I get not enter into succes in an Ajax call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a problem with my code in Ajax, The problem is that when I run the ajax query, PHP access to the file but does not enter succes What can I be doing wrong?

My code is:

```
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "<?php echo get_template_directory_uri().'/rep.php'; ?>",
        data: { id: <?php echo  $race_iden;?>},
        dataType:"json",
        success: function(data) {
                var tam=data.length;
                alert(tam);
                var datos=eval(data[tam]);
                document.write(datos);
                for(i=0; i< datos.length; i++){
                alert(datos[i].lat);
                console.log(data[i].lat);
            }                           
        }
    });
    clearInterval(intId);
   }

});
```

Comment: Check the console for errors.

Comment: one problem is in data. you need to try  data: { id: "<?php echo  $race_iden;?>"}, check once

Comment: @anantkumarsingh it is not needed.

Comment: the console no errors,

Comment: and do not use eval(), you can use jQuery.parseJSON() , / or JSON.parse()

Comment: when I run it would have to skip at least one alert but do not and are sure that the file access rep.php

Comment: I'll try to json.parser or the other solution

Comment: does not work, the problem has to be that does not enter succes, how can I know whether to come in and why?

Comment: After **`success: function() {//your code..}`** add a comma `,` and this: `error: function() {alert("there was an error");}` and check if the alert is shown.

Comment: @sgtBOSE how can you know that `$race_iden` is not a string??

Comment: $race_iden is a string with the id that load of the bd

Comment: @CliffBurton the alert is show...

Comment: In console you can see the request your ajax does and the response too. Check your ajax request the correct url, does post the data you want, and the response is a correct json string.

Comment: When I return only one result in the query works but when I return several results in the json is when it fails

Comment: @user3449918 check in console, in the _source_ section of your browser, what are the results of your `PHP` outputs: (`echo get_template_directory_uri().'/rep.php';` in the **URL** and `$race_iden` in **data**) because if the alert is shown then you have an error, probably in your dynamically-inserted url

Comment: The values is correct in boht case

Comment: your rep.php page has to return json!

Comment: That url results an empty page.

Comment: Are you sure that your `rep.php` return `JSON`??

Comment: no, the url is well, but, only have code php not html

Comment: my rep.php call echo json_encode($puntos);
 in the end

Comment: $puntos is a array of point of bd

Comment: When rep. php return                                                                                 0: {id: "1", lat: "36.383292000000000", lon: "-5.104591000000000",…}
work well but when when instead of returning a result returns more than one does not work

Comment: What returns rep.php when there are more than one results?

Comment: for example:   2: [{id: "1", lat: "36.383292000000000", lon: "-5.104591000000000",…},…]
0: {id: "1", lat: "36.383292000000000", lon: "-5.104591000000000",…}
1: {id: "2", lat: "36.400703000000000", lon: "-5.129997000000000",…}
2: {id: "3", lat: "36.368663000000000", lon: "-5.132869000000000",…}

Comment: That looks not like a valid json string. It looks like you echo the json encoded array and after that you echo each elements of the array.

Comment: I dont understan @MIvanIsten

Comment: The output you wrote in your comment is garbage, can't be a valid json string. Please show us an [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). At least an working url where we can see the output of your rep.php.

Comment: http://miregata.com/race/4838 .... if you use chrome in **network** you can see the file **rep.php** when load

Comment: Sorry I can finally found the error, The file rep.php had a bad location the **}** therefore the output cant be valid

Comment: It looks like your json_encode() is in a loop, and you echo it after each element added to the array.

Comment: @MIvanIsten already work well the problem was '}' bad location, Thanks for you help